# How do I keep track of a global variable in a Windows Forms MDI application?

Tags: c#, winforms, global-variables, mdi

Is there an acceptable practice for keeping track of the value of a global variable in winforms - similar to keeping an item in session for a web application? In my windows mdi form application, the user selects a value and then needs to be able to access it while using several child forms. I'm not a windows developer by trade and I don't want to choose a solution that doesn't make sense to the next developer that inherits this project.

I searched for an answer to this already and couldn't find what I needed so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Basically, you want a "global" variable? Create a public static Class, and in it , create a public static variable.

Comment: There is only ever one MDI parent form, that's a good place for it.

Comment: Regarding being put on hold - I reviewed the help center as best as I could before posting this and tried to phrase it in such as way to explain that I need help and don't know how to handle the problem. All resolutions to a problem are somewhat opinion based as they reflect our individual experiences. Again, I am looking for specific help to resolve a specific problem. Please remove the -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store application-scope settings in the .settings file under Project->Properties->Settings. Please refer to MSDN for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.110).aspx.

You could also use your own custom static class to store and share settings between classes and forms:

```
public static class ApplicationService
{
    public static string YourSetting { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
//set in Form1:
ApplicationService.YourSetting = "x";

//retrieve in Form2:
var setting = ApplicationService.YourSetting = "x";
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the specific help I needed. My question was marked as opinion based, which is frustrating.